# The convolution of two continuous functions is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am just learning about convolutions in a measure theory course.  We are given that the convolution of two functions $f$ and $g$ is defined as:

$$f*g(t) = \int f(u)g(t-u) \,du$$

Now, I would like to show that, if $f$ and $g$ are continuous with compact support, then the convolution $f*g$ is also continuous.  I can't seem to wrap my head around how to show this.

Comment: I think you've written your convolution wrong.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the convolution $\displaystyle (f*g)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u) g(t-u)\,du$ of a continuous function $f$ with an integrable function $g,$ i.e. $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty |g(u)| \,du <+\infty,$ is continuous. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g$ is uniformly continuous.  Take $\delta > 0$ so that $|g(x) - g(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$.  Then if $|s-t| < \delta$, 
$$|f*g(t) - f*g(s)| \le \int |f(u)| |g(u-t) - g(u-s)|\; du \le \epsilon \int |f(u)|\; du$$

Comment: Uniform continuity was exactly what I was missing. This makes sense now, thanks!

Comment: @Robert Israel if $f,g \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ does it imply they are continuous with compact support? I have a similar question I just posted just the assumption is $f,g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: @HossienSahebjame No it does not.