# Measurable set in a square, and containing a Cartesian square

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subseteq [0,1]^2$ be a measurable subset with full measure, $\mu(A)=1$. For $X\subseteq [0,1]$, $D(X)$ denotes the diagonal of $X$, i.e. $D(X)=\lbrace (x,x) \ | \ x \in X \rbrace$.

**Question.** Must there always be an $X$ with positive measure such that $(X \times X) \setminus D(X) \subseteq A$?

My thoughts : if $A_1=(0,\frac{1}{2}) \times (\frac{1}{2},1)$, $A_2=(\frac{1}{2},1) \times (0,\frac{1}{2})$ and $A=A_1\cup A_2$, then $A$ has measure $\frac{1}{2}$, and there is no $X$ containing more than two elements such that $X\times X \setminus D(X) \subseteq A$. I tried to find similar examples with $\mu(A)\gt \frac{1}{2}$ but failed. This leads me to ask the following :

**Second question.** Let $A$ be as above ($A\subseteq [0,1]^2$ with $\mu(A)=1$). Must there always be an $X$ containing at least three elements such that $(X \times X) \setminus D(X) \subseteq A$?

**Update** According to the answer linked in PhoemueX's comment below, the answer to the first question is no if $\mu(A)=1$ is replaced with $\mu(A)=1-\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$. Indeed, this answer produces an $E\subseteq [0,1]^2$ with $\mu(E)=1-\varepsilon$, such that $E$ contains no "measurable rectangles", i.e. $E$ contains no $Y\times Z$ where $Y,Z$ have positive measure. Then we may take $A=E \cup D([0,1])$.

Comment: This might be interesting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42748/measurable-rectangles-inside-a-non-null-set

Comment: Might be useful thinking about a discrete version of the second question: specifically if you have a subset $A$ of $\{1,...,n\}^2$ of cardinality more than $n^2/2$ then is it necessarily true that $A$ contains some $X\times X \backslash \Delta(X)$ where cardinality of $X$ is bigger than 2. I thought about it for a bit but got nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No to the first question. Let $A=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2 : x-y \notin \Bbb Q\}.$ Then $A$ has full measure in $[0,1]^2$.

By Steinhaus' theorem, $A$ contains no measurable rectangles, that is, sets of the form $B\times C$ where $B,C\subset [0,1]$ are measurable and have positive measure. (Note: I am using the version of Steinhaus' theorem from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4319073/let-a-b-be-two-measurable-set-with-positive-measure-show-that-a-b-contains).)

Assume that there was some measurable $X\subset [0,1]$ of positive measure such that $(X\times X)\backslash D(X) \subset A$. Then we can choose $a\in[0,1]$ such that $B:=[0,a)\cap X$ has positive measure and $C:=(a,1]\cap X$ also has positive measure. Note that $B\times C \subset (X\times X)\backslash D(X) \subset A$. Thus $A$ contains a measurable rectangle, a contradiction.